# thead position absolute not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, html-table, internet-explorer-7, fixed-header-tables

I try to make a table header fixed when scoll down on pages. The problem is in IE7, the **thead** are not absolute but are showing in the "right" positions. It need to fly over the table. It works perfect in FireFox 11

I have a table structure as follow:

```
<span id="MyTable">
    <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="100%">
    <thead class="tableFloatingHeader">
    <tr>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
<thead class="tableFloatingHeaderOriginal">
    <tr>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
        <th>t</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><b>Total</b></td>
    <td></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    <td align="right"><b>2</b></td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
```

CSS

```
.tableFloatingHeader {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: none;
    left: auto;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function UpdateTableHeaders() {
            $("div.divTableWithFloatingHeader").each(function() {
                var originalHeaderRow = $(".tableFloatingHeaderOriginal");
                var floatingHeaderRow = $(".tableFloatingHeader");
                var offset = $(this).offset();
                var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
                if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + $(this).height())) {
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("display", "block");
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("top", Math.min(scrollTop - offset.top, $(this).height() - floatingHeaderRow.height()) + "px");

                    // Copy cell widths from original header
                    $("th", floatingHeaderRow).each(function(index) {
                        var cellWidth = $("th", originalHeaderRow).eq(index).css('width');
                        $(this).css('width', cellWidth);
                    });

                    // Copy row width from whole table
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("width", $(this).css("width"));
                }
                else {
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("display", "none");
                    floatingHeaderRow.css("top", "0px");
                }
            });
        }
        UpdateTableHeaders();
        $(window).scroll(UpdateTableHeaders);
        $(window).resize(UpdateTableHeaders);
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, basically add a conditional CSS expression style for IE7.  I don't like using expressions, but IE7 is another animal.

```
thead tr {
     position: relative;
     top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
    }
```

http://geekswithblogs.net/LSheu/archive/2009/01/30/css-table-scrolling-with-fixed-header-for-ie-7.aspx

Edit* Wrong URL